# How-to create a DVD from a network repository

Tags: repository, suse

I have to install a Suse Enterprise Server 11.4 on some servers that have no connection to the internet. On them I have to install some software from unofficial repositories, as MariaDB connectors, which are available at http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ghostlyrat/SLE_11_SP4/

If the server had an internet connection I could just add this repository to the sources list, but as it's not the case I want to create a DVD with this repository, to pack it together with the 2 official DVDs. Of course I could send the RPMs, but I want the opperators to just add the third DVD to the sources list and then proceed.

How can it be done? I've checked the structure of the official DVDs and they doesn't match the network repository structure.

UPDATE/SOLVED: actually the different structure was just because the repositories were of different type, yast repositories the official ones and yum repository the unofficial one. I created an ISO with the contents of the repository and I could successfully to add it to the sources list.

The ISO had the `.repo` file at root folder, and the folders (and their contents) `noarch`, `repodata`, `src` and `x86_64` (as this one was the architecture of my servers). There's no need to include other architectures' folders.

Comment: Update: I've checked both repositories (official and unofficial) and the former are YasT repositories and the latter a yum repository. Maybe that explains the different structure.

I'll try just downloading the repository and creating an ISO with its contents.

Comment: Can you not just copy all the files/directories under your http resource to a DVD and then use it? YaST notices the format of the repostiroy (e.g. YaST vs YUM vs ...).